# How to upload a file to s3 bucket from razor using C# (ASP.Net Core)

Tags: amazon-s3, blazor

I have a razor component which is having a browse button to upload file. Now how do i connect the file uploaded to s3.

Comment: Will be good to please provide some code for the file upload you have and any other code you have tried for s3 upload.

Answer (score 1):

To upload the files to your S3 storage you can use the sample code below:

Install the .net sdk from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.S3): `Install-Package AWSSDK.S3`

Add using statements:

```
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Transfer;
```

And a method to upload a file (3 options provided here copied from [AWS S3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileDotNet.html))

```
private static async Task UploadFileAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);

        // Option 1. Upload a file. The file name is used as the object key name.
        await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(filePath, bucketName);
        Console.WriteLine("Upload 1 completed");

        // Option 2. Specify object key name explicitly.
        await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(filePath, bucketName, keyName);
        Console.WriteLine("Upload 2 completed");

        // Option 3. Upload data from a type of System.IO.Stream.
        using (var fileToUpload = 
            new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(fileToUpload,
                                       bucketName, keyName);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Upload 3 completed");
    }
    catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
    {
        // catch exception
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // catch exception
    }

}
```

More details about uploading and an advanced upload method [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileDotNet.html).

Comment: This is the clearest answer I have found anywhere online for how to do this upload from a Razor page.  However, it seems to me incomplete.  For example, don't we need to somewhere authenticate the page so that we can upload to the S3 bucket?

Comment: Thanks. So there are various ways to authenticate. For example, you can authenticate by providing an access key and secrets which is what I am doing but have not mentioned it here.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification!  Would you be able to point me to some documentation that explicitly talks about doing it this way?